# Passing decimal valus in angular2 routes params

Tags: angular, routes, router

I have a angular2 application where i am passing data to the route using the parameters from URL in matrix notation.

> Sample URL:
>   http://localhost/explore;am=Birla%20Sun%20Life,SBI;q=;f=0;r=10;ag=0;ra=;c=;sc=;se=;so=;ar=;o=;qt=filter;

This seems to work well. But when I pass a decimal value in the same URL as a parameter value I am getting message shown as:

> ```
> Sample URL: http://10.1.0.100/explore;am=Birla%20Sun%20Life,SBI;q=;f=0;r=10;ag=0;ra=;c=;sc=;se=;so=;ar=;o=;qt=filter;bq=birla%2Bamc%2B2.5;
>
> output: Cannot GET /explore;am=Birla%20Sun%20Life,SBI;q=;f=0;r=10;ag=0;ra=;c=;sc=;se=;so=;ar=;o=;qt=filter;bq=birla%2Bamc%2B2.5;
> ```

Can you please help me on figure out this behavior. I do realize that its due to "." special character and i also tries replacing it with %2E but that also doesn't seems to work. Is it some kind of limitation of angular2 route params?